# Android - How to perform additional action on app widget click

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget

I have an app widget which when clicked opens a fragment.

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
        .setGraph(R.navigation.my_nav_graph)
        .setDestination(R.id.my_fragment)
        .createPendingIntent()
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_view, pendingIntent)
```

When the widget is clicked, along with opening the fragment, I need to send an analytics event.

I would like to avoid passing arguments to the pending intent and handling the sending of the analytics event inside *my_fragment* but rather do it in the widget somehow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No. You have no means of having an app widget take action, other than via a `PendingIntent`.